# Zend: Call an action on every page load

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I'm trying to accomplish a permanent login with cookies in Zend Framework.
Therefore I want to check on every page load if a specific cookie is set and if so call the `loginAction` that is in my `IndexController` (the action works fine) passing two parameters from the cookie.

I have two questions:

**1. Where should I place the function call so it is executed every time? Bootstrap.php, layout.phtml, index.php or somewhere else?**

**2. How can I call the `loginAction` from outside the `IndexController` while passing the parameters?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Definitely not layout.phtml (You views should preferably only have HTML output). If your application has multiple bootstraps, you can put this function to index.php, so you wouldn't have the same code in different bootstraps. If you only have one bootstrap, then call the function there.
2. `IndexController::loginAction($param1, $param2);`

Comment: I get `Class 'IndexController' not found` and `loginAction` is not a static function

Comment: Use Autoloader to load the class - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510493/extending-the-indexcontroller-with-a-basecontroller-in-zend for this

Answer (score 0):

I think that a plugin would be more appropriate in this case.

> preDispatch() is called before an action is dispatched by the
>   dispatcher. This callback allows for proxy or filter behavior. By
>   altering the request and resetting its dispatched flag (via
>   Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract::setDispatched(false)), the current
>   action may be skipped and/or replaced.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html